# Struts2 i18n in java class

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I have a Struts2 web application that uses an i18n properties file for localization.
The `getText` method works perfectly in jsp and in a action class `getText("some.identifier")`.

But how can i use it in java-classes that are not an action-class? In other words, classes that do not have access to the `getText` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ResourceBundle labels =
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyBundle", currentLocale);
Enumeration bundleKeys = labels.getKeys();

while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
    String value = labels.getString(key);
    System.out.println("key = " + key + ", " + 
               "value = " + value);
}
```

Something like this will read your resource bundle

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to re-load the bundle. You can use the following code to tap into the copy that Struts has loaded:

```
LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(key, ActionContext.getContext().getLocale());
```

Keep in mind that `ActionContext` is thread local, so if you attempt to call this from a different thread than the one processing the request, you'll run into an error.

An overloaded form of the method takes an object array as the third parameter, if you need to pass arguments to the localized message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ResourceBuldle to load the properties file and get the desired properties.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you have a short code-sample on how to?